# Twitter Bootstrap relative width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, width

I have two column (A and B) and i would make them dependent on the content - images (1,2,3).
For example, when 3 pictures - then First Column - 30% width, Second - 70%,
When 2 pics - 20%/80%
When 1 pic - 10%/90%
Image[image: picture]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Bootstrap is your best bet for achieving that type of layout. This is about as close as I could get it

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <img src="#" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <img src="#" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <img src="#" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">right</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <img src="#" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <img src="#" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">right</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <img src="#" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6">right</div>
</div>
```